# Handling Enter Key in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a text field and a button.
By default, this button submits a form when someone presses the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key on their keyboard.
When someone is typing in the text field, I want to capture each key pressed. If the key is an `@` symbol, I want to do something special.

If the key pressed is the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key, I want to do something special as well. The latter is the one giving me challenges. Currently, I have this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ffgvw3yr/2/), which includes this code:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#myApp',
  data: {
    emailAddress: '',
    log: ''
  },
  methods: {
    validateEmailAddress: function(e) {
      if (e.keyCode === 13) {
        alert('Enter was pressed');
      } else if (e.keyCode === 50) {
        alert('@ was pressed');
      }      
      this.log += e.key;
    },
    
    postEmailAddress: function() {
      this.log += '\n\nPosting';
    }
});
```

In my example, I can't seem to press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key without it submitting the form. Yet, I would expect the `validateEmailAddress` function to at least fire first so that I could capture it. But, that does not seem to be happening.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I see no form in your fiddle?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

### Event Modifiers

You can refer to [event modifiers](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Event-Modifiers) in vuejs to prevent form submission on `enter` key.

> It is a very common need to call `event.preventDefault()` or `event.stopPropagation()` inside event handlers.

> Although we can do this easily inside methods, it would be better if the methods can be purely about data logic rather than having to deal with DOM event details.

> To address this problem, Vue provides event modifiers for `v-on`. Recall that modifiers are directive postfixes denoted by a dot.

```html
<form v-on:submit.prevent="<method>">
  ...
</form>
```

As the documentation states, this is syntactical sugar for `e.preventDefault()` and will stop the unwanted form submission on press of enter key.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/hufa5woo/) is a working fiddle.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#myApp',
  data: {
    emailAddress: '',
    log: ''
  },
  methods: {
    validateEmailAddress: function(e) {
      if (e.keyCode === 13) {
        alert('Enter was pressed');
      } else if (e.keyCode === 50) {
        alert('@ was pressed');
      }      
      this.log += e.key;
    },
    
    postEmailAddress: function() {
            this.log += '\n\nPosting';
    },
    noop () {
      // do nothing ?
    }
  }
})
```

```css
html, body, #editor {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  color: #333;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.2.4/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="myApp" style="padding:2rem; background-color:#fff;">
<form v-on:submit.prevent="noop">
  <input type="text" v-model="emailAddress" v-on:keyup="validateEmailAddress" />
  <button type="button" v-on:click="postEmailAddress" >Subscribe</button> 
  <br /><br />
  
  <textarea v-model="log" rows="4"></textarea>  
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: I had to modify this to `@keyup.native="validateEmailAddress" for it to work with my setup in vue-cli 3

Answer (score 263):

In vue 2, You can catch enter event with `v-on:keyup.enter` check the documentation:

> https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Key-Modifiers

I leave a *very simple* example:

```js
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {msg: ''},
  methods: {
    onEnter: function() {
       this.msg = 'on enter event';
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <input v-on:keyup.enter="onEnter" />
  <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: This gave me the hint I needed. With Buefy I needed to add native for b-input: `v-on:keyup.native.enter="onEnter"`

Comment: You can also use @keyup.enter="doSomething"

Comment: v-on:keyup.native.enter="onEnter"  is only valid with components not on button.

Comment: Do we always need an input to detect key presses? I'm trying to control a Buefy carousel with the arrows and esc key (when in fullscreen).

Comment: buefy input and chrome I needed @keydown.enter.native="doSomething"  https://github.com/bootstrap-vue/bootstrap-vue/issues/936#issuecomment-325248549

Answer (score 44):

For enter event handling you can use

1. `@keyup.enter` or
2. `@keyup.13`

13 is the keycode of enter. For @ key event, the keycode is 50. So you can use `@keyup.50`.

For example:

```html
<input @keyup.50="atPress()" />
```

Comment: Is there a site that lists the mapping between characters and numbers (like 50 and @)? I couldn't find it in the Vue documentation.

Comment: can i use multiple keys? something like @keydown.1.2 ?

Comment: Yes, <input @keyup.50="atPress" @keyup.13="atPress" />

Answer (score 41):

This event works to me:

```
@keyup.enter.native="onEnter".
```

Answer (score 25):

You forget a '}' before the last line (to close the "methods {...").

This code works :

```js
Vue.config.keyCodes.atsign = 50;

new Vue({
  el: '#myApp',
  data: {
    emailAddress: '',
    log: ''
  },
  methods: {
  
    onEnterClick: function() {
     alert('Enter was pressed');
    },
    
    onAtSignClick: function() {
     alert('@ was pressed');
    },
    
    postEmailAddress: function() {
   this.log += '\n\nPosting';
    }
  }
})
```

```css
html, body, #editor {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  color: #333;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://vuejs.org/js/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="myApp" style="padding:2rem; background-color:#fff;">

  <input type="text" v-model="emailAddress" v-on:keyup.enter="onEnterClick" v-on:keyup.atsign="onAtSignClick" />
  
  <button type="button" v-on:click="postEmailAddress" >Subscribe</button> 
  <br /><br />
  
  <textarea v-model="log" rows="4"></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a site that lists the mapping between characters and numbers (like 50 and @)? I couldn't find it in the Vue documentation

Answer (score 17):

You can also pass events down into child components with something like this:

```
<CustomComponent
    @keyup.enter="handleKeyUp"
/>
```

...

```
<template>
    <div>
        <input
            type="text"
            v-on="$listeners"
        >
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'CustomComponent',

    mounted() {
        console.log('listeners', this.$listeners)
    },
}
</script>
```

That works well if you have a pass-through component and want the listeners to go onto a specific element.

Answer (score 6):

**Vue 3**

In Vue 3, this code works if you want to listen event enter in input:

```
<input @keyup.enter="onPressEnter" />
```

Or maybe you want your event to fire when the key is pressed, rather than when it’s released:

```
<input @keydown.enter="onPressEnter" />
```

Answer (score 1):

you are missing a closing curly bracket for methods

```
new Vue({
  el: '#myApp',
  data: {
    emailAddress: '',
    log: ''
  },
  methods: {
    validateEmailAddress: function(e) {
      if (e.keyCode === 13) {
        alert('Enter was pressed');
      } else if (e.keyCode === 50) {
        alert('@ was pressed');
      }      
      this.log += e.key;
    },

    postEmailAddress: function() {
      this.log += '\n\nPosting';
    }
  }//add this closing bracket and everything is fine
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how you would write it in Vue3 with Composition API.

```html
<script setup>
function callOnEnter() {
  console.log("Enter key pressed");
}
</script>

<template>
  <input type="text" @keyup.enter="callOnEnter" />
</template>
```

More details are available here: https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/event-handling.html#key-modifiers